# How can I get pass a value to a js method that was entered in html (LWC)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, js

While experimenting with LWC I wrote the following code:

```
                    <lightning-layout-item size="1">
                        <div>
                            <lightning-input type="text" name="city" label="Enter city"></lightning-input>
                            <lightning-button icon-name="utility:search" size="small" alternative-text="search" onclick={handleChange}></lightning-button>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
```

I want to get city in the js method, but I can't get it:

```
handleChange(event) {
        let inputCity = this.template.querySelector('city');
        console.log('city: ' + inputCity);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`city` would be interpreted as a element/component name, you want to use:

```
    let inputCity = this.template.querySelector(`[name="city"]`);
```

Or even:

```
    let inputCity = this.template.querySelector(`lightning-input`);
```

Since you currently only have one element that would match.

Comment: `let inputCity = this.template.querySelector(`[name="city"]`);` - returns: _null_.
`let inputCity = this.template.querySelector(`lightning-input`);` - returns: _SecureElement: [object HTMLElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }_. But adding `.value` I get my value.
And if I have several `lightning-input` elements, how do I get the value I need?